# bash script to sftp files with a password from remote directories to local folders

Tags: bash, sftp

How to write a `bash` script using `sftp` command to download files?
I can use the following command to login to the remote machine, however I need to type in the password manually.

```
bash-3.2$ sftp -o "Port 22022" mike@s-edm-ssh.local.files.stack.com
mike@s-edm-ssh.local.files.stack.com's password: 
Connected to s-edm-ssh.local.files.stack.com.
sftp>
```

How to do the `sftp` without the password prompt?

If I like to download `aaa.txt` file at `/remote/mike/files` to my local directory `/local/mike/downloaded`, how to build a script to do all of these work?

Comment: You need to setup public key authentication - https://hkn.eecs.berkeley.edu/~dhsu/ssh_public_key_howto.html

Answer (score 5):

Since `sftp` runs over [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell), you can place your public key on the remote server.

If for some reason you can't place your key on the server, then you can write an [Expect](http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm) script to `send` your password when the prompt appears. See this [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect#Examples).